# Dynamics CRM Online and Impersonation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, impersonation

I'm using a code from CRM2011KIT "**CRM Online from PHP**". And I'm able to create or update entities without any problem from PHP.

But now we need to use **impersonation**, and I cannot find any example or documents how to do that using **LiveID authorization, CRM Online and simple XML requests** (of course I'm not able to use SDK from PHP).

I will be glad to hear that somebody solve the problem like mine or have some idea. But I even cannot imagine where to place "**CallerID**" in current soap XML requests

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this?
[CRM Online 2011 WebServices - SOAP Only Client](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CRM-Online-2011-WebServices-14913a16)

They do bare SOAP requests and there is support for LiveID & Office365 logins

Comment: They do no impersonation, at least I found no one in their SOAP requests. So it does not help unfortunately, I already have working SOAP requests in PHP